# I need to rewrite url in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url www.example.com/product/1 to www.example.com/en/product/1 when user chooses english language. (he will click on a select box that will toggle the language and set a session called 'language')

I cannot choose the django 1.4 which supports this feature. We are advised to stick with django 1.3.

Hence I tried a middleware, but as it turns out, the middleware runs for each request resulting in a endless loop.

```
class urlrewrite():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'i' in request.session:
            if request.session.get('i','') != 0:
                print "session"
                request.session['i'] = request.session['i'] + 1
            else:
                request.session['i'] = 0
        else:
            request.session['i'] = 0

        print "request.session['i']", request.session['i']    

        if request.session.get('i','') == SOME_CONSTANT and request.session.get('django_language','') == 'en':
            del request.session['i']
            return HttpResponseRedirect("en/"+request.META['PATH_INFO'])
```

Ofcourse, it doesnt work. This runs for every single request.

Kindly help me out.

Thank you

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/9923178/how-do-i-rewrite-this-url-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write this yourself, use someone else's hard work.

Try [django-cms](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/advanced/i18n.html)'s solution first.

==== EDIT ====

You do not need to used django-cms, just have it installed and use their Multilingual URL Middleware. This interfaces with django's regular internationalisation machinery.

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/advanced/i18n.html

Comment: Hi thomas we made the bold move of updgrading to django 1.4 for this existing project. Please guide me towards a tutorial of using locale url using django 1.4

Comment: "To install it, include 'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware' in your project’s MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting." 

Pretty much one of the first things on the page i linked you to

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using a little trick in your `urls.py` file, as shown by this part of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to.

You keep the same view, it will simple have a different URL. I think thats what you want. Make sure you choose the 1.3 version of the docs, I believe there has been some changes.